# Brackets on AngularJS module make my web-page blank

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this piece of code

```
(function() {
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('e2EApp');
    app.controller('SearchController', SearchController);

SearchController.$inject = ['$scope','$state', '$http'];


function SearchController ($scope, $state, $http) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.doSearch = function() {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: "http://localhost:8080/api/search/" + vm.search.searchTerm + "/" + vm.search.sortTerm
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            if (response.status == 200) {
                vm.search.users = response.data
            }
        });
    };

}})();
```

and when I put the brackets inside angular.module like this

```
angular.module('e2EApp', []);
```

The web-page that has the module name 'e2Epp' is blank after I save the file and refresh the page. When I remove them It all works again. I want to add 'ngSanitize' inside the brackets but even if I don't and leave them empty the problem still persists. Any clue about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[In case you missed it in the AngularJS documentation:](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module)

> Passing one argument retrieves an existing `angular.Module`, whereas passing more than one argument creates a new `angular.Module`

In your snippet, `angular.module('e2EApp')` would retrieve an existing module definition so you can augment it with other definitions (e.g. `SearchController`). On the other hand, `angular.module('e2EApp', [])` defines a new module with no AngularJS module dependencies.

My guess is that you've defined `e2EApp` elsewhere.

If you want to add the `ngSanitize` dependency, add it to the original module definition.

[Here's a basic example to clarify these module call behaviours](http://plnkr.co/edit/H6klam?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was exactly the problem, although I have problems using sanitize properly. Now my web-page is up again but sanitize doesn't seem to work. I have a source with the cdn path of the library.

Comment: No problem. You haven't mentioned if you're using a JS bundler. If you're simply including AngularJS dependencies via `script` tags, you could check that the inclusion of `angular-sanitize.js` comes after `angular.js`.

Comment: Thanks miqid. I finally managed to solve all my problems thanks to you. Much appreciated!